# does expression encoder 3 supports two audio sources?

Tags: .net, expression-encoder

Is it possible using expression encoder 3 add two audio devices and then encode both input into one stereo file?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late, as I just started a project into this.
Not sure about expression encoder 3 but as they didn't do much of modifications in encoder 4 for multiple devices, I would say they are both the same.

That brings us to the problem which is:

It does support but depends on the OS.
As of right now I know for sure XP and anything under does not support it.

Comment: do you mean that win7 supports?

Comment: It should, I am still running some test, I can tell you for certain in a couple days, as right now, I am nowhere near my program or a windows 7.