# multiple audio streams in smooth streaming manifest

Tags: encoding, expression-encoder-sdk, expression-encoder-4

How to add multiple audio tracks in a manifest like [THIS](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/content/smf/smoothcontent/elephantsdream/Elephants_Dream_1024-h264-st-aac.ism/manifest).

Actually I have two publish points, one for Video+Audio and one for Audio only. I want to play both feeds in [SMF](https://smf.codeplex.com) together.

EE doesn't support [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337813/does-expression-encoder-3-supports-two-audio-sources).

How to do it? How they added multiple audio tracks in elephantsdream on demand manifest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that in elephantsdream they have used some hardware encoders to manage multiple audio tracks.

I'm using SMF's [PIP (Picture-In-Picture)](http://smf.blob.core.windows.net/docs/PictureInPicture.docx) to manage two manifest and/or audio feeds.